# Soft Key Pad Push Frame Layout while Enter the text in Edit Box in android

Tags: android, fragment, android-softkeyboard, android-framelayout

I have used `framelayout` to be shown one custom alert dialog box where i have used one fragment to replace the `framelayout` in one activity, Now i have been facing issues as push frame layout up on the screen while enter the text from the soft keypad. i have used

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

this is working fine only when show the soft key pad when touch on the edit box. but when started to enter the characters in the edit box , the layout again push up with bottom buttons with keypad.

i don't know why this is happening even i was put the above code in `onCreateView()`.

Please help me if somebody got any idea to do.

Comment: You are not the one facing the problem. Your layout goes up, because your `softKey` pad does not **overlap** your layout. So when SoftKey pad is opened your layout will be pulled up, and it's bottom will be set on the top of softKey pad.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, then how to fix it?

Comment: I haven't fixed yet and also met another guy on SO having same problem. Neither he could solve it, he had to change his view. I'm also thinking to change my layout view